# Laravel difficult union query with pagination

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, union

I have these tables, which may be in mysql or postgres database:

```
                                                                           
|===============================================================================|
|                                      articles                                 |
|===============================================================================|
|id|user_id|state|       title        |text|created_at|updated_at|abstract|image|
|==|=======|=====|====================|====|==========|==========|========|=====|
|1 | 1     | 5   |L'hopital rule      |... |2014-12-05|          | ...    | ... |
|2 | 2     | 5   |Gaussian quadrature |... |2012-11-13|2014-12-05| ...    | ... |
|3 | 2     | 5   |Gauss elimination   |... |2013-07-18|2014-03-09| ...    | ... |
|4 | 3     | 5   |Plant cell structure|... |2013-09-10|2013-12-15| ...    | ... |
|5 | 4     | 5   |Game theory         |... |2011-02-15|2012-11-30| ...    | ... |
|                                       .  .  .                                 |
|===============================================================================|

|===========|      |====================|      |===========|                    
| tag_groups|      |       tags         |      |   users   |                    
|===========|      |====================|      |===========|                    
|id|  name  |      |id|id_article|id_tag|      |id|  name  |                    
|==|========|      |==|==========|======|      |==|========|                    
|1 |Math    |      |1 | 1        | 1    |      |1 |Tom Ther|                    
|2 |Calculus|      |2 | 1        | 2    |      |2 |May Nick|                    
|3 |Gradient|      |3 | 2        | 1    |      |3 |Math Ria|                    
|4 |Geometry|      |4 | 3        | 1    |      |4 |Gauss Li|                    
|  .  .  .  |      |      .  .  .       |      |  .  .  .  |                    
|===========|      |====================|      |===========|
```

Let us have `$query = "th"`. Let's than have `$like_query = "%th%"`
I would like to search by `$like_query` string in articles with the following logic:

1. First results should be the articles having the tag_group.name matching the `$like_query` string. Here it would be articles with `id=1`, `id=2` and `id=3`.
2. Next results should be articles matching the article title. So `id=5` is added.
3. Then, articles created by users with matching name are added. So article with `id=3` is added.
4. In the end, articles matching with the text are added.

All the articles have to be in this order and there must not be any duplicates. 
I have created following code with `build_sql` function in laravel:

```
function like($string, $escape_char = '\\') {
    return str_replace(
        array($escape_char, '_', '%'),
        array($escape_char.$escape_char, $escape_char.'_', $escape_char.'%'),
        $string
    );
}

function wild($string) {                                                
    return DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote('%'.like($string).'%');    
}                                                                       

function build_sql($quoted_query) {                                     
    return "                                                            
        SELECT DISTINCT                                                 
          articles.id, articles.user_id, articles.state, articles.title,
          articles.image, articles.abstract, articles.text, articles.created_at,
          articles.updated_at                                           
        FROM (                                                          
          SELECT articles.*, ord                                        
          FROM (                                                        
            SELECT articles.*, 1 ord                                    
            FROM articles                                               
            LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id_article = articles.id             
            LEFT JOIN tag_groups ON tags.id_tag = tag_groups.id         
            WHERE articles.state = 5 AND tag_groups.name ILIKE $quoted_query
            UNION                                                       

            SELECT articles.*, 2 ord                                    
            FROM articles                                               
            WHERE articles.state = 5 AND articles.title ILIKE $quoted_query
            UNION                                                       

            SELECT articles.*, 3 ord                                    
            FROM articles                                               
            LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id              
            WHERE articles.state = 5 AND users.name ILIKE $quoted_query 
            UNION                                                       

            SELECT articles.*, 4 ord                                    
            FROM articles                                               
            WHERE articles.state = 5 AND articles.text ILIKE $quoted_query
          ) articles                                                    
          ORDER BY ord ASC, articles.updated_at DESC                    
        ) articles;                                                     
    "                                                                       
}

$articles = DB::table((DB::raw($build_sql(wild($_query)))))->distinct();

$maxPages = ceil(count($articles->get()) / 9);                          
return View::make('index', array(                                       
            'articles' => $articles->simplePaginate(9),
            'maxPages' => $maxPages,                                    
));
```

This doesn't work and I don't know what I should do. Is there a way how to write it nice using eloquent models? Or if not, how should I update the build_sql string?

Comment: is `$quoted_query` escaped and quoted?

Comment: `wild($_query)` handles that, and when I print the result from `build_sql`, it is escaped and quoted there.